# How can I prevent my Python web-scraper from stopping?

Tags: python, python-requests, continuous-integration

Ahoy! I've written a quick (Python) program that grabs the occupancy of a climbing gym every five minutes for later analysis. I'd like it to run non-stop, but I've noticed that after a couple hours pass, one of two things will happen.

1. It will detect a keyboard interrupt (which I did not enter) and stop, or
2. It will simply stop writing to the `.csv` file without showing any failure in the shell.

Here is the code:

```py
import os
os.chdir('~/Documents/Other/g1_capacity') #ensure program runs in correct directory if opened elsewhere

import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import csv

def get_count():
    url = 'https://portal.rockgympro.com/portal/public/b01ab221559163c5e9a73e078fe565aa/occupancy?&iframeid=occupancyCounter&fId='
    text = requests.get(url).text
    line = ""

    for item in text.split("\n"):
        if "\'count\'" in item:
            line = (item.strip())
            
    count = int(line.split(":")[1][0:-1]) #really gross way to get count number for this specific source

    return count

while True: #run until manual stop

    with open('g1_occupancy.csv', mode='a') as occupancy:
        occupancy_writer = csv.writer(occupancy)
        occupancy_writer.writerow([datetime.now(), get_count()]) #append new line to .csv with timestamp and current count

    time.sleep(60 * 5) #wait five minutes before adding new line
```

I am new to web scraping (in fact, this is my first time) and I'm wondering if anyone might have a suggestion to help eliminate the issue I described above. Many thanks!

Comment: you could use `try ... except` to show error message and handle error without terminating progream.

Comment: When it stops writing to the csv file, it may be waiting for the web page to return. Print the current time every time `get_count` is called so you can see if the script is still running.